# Question put on hold for being "too broad", but is it?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600823/undecided-between-using-exceptions-or-reporting-error-messages) question of mine has been put on hold for being too broad.

I've specified the domain (numerical analysis), the application (integration) and the scenario where I'm in doubt about if I should use exceptions or report error messages (procedure fails to converge and improper user input).

I even ask explicitly

> I was thinking about a scenario where exceptions are thrown by the
>   library routines in the circumstances I mentioned above and caught by
>   the user. Would that be acceptable? If not, what would be a good
>   approach?

Is this still too broad? I mean the title may appear so but does the actual question?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's not "too broad" then it will be "primarily opinion-based" (*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*) which is also a close reason. Pick your poison.

Comment: I see. Oh, well. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can I ask why you felt obligated to post that question? You are already ahead of the crowd because you managed to think up an actual working solution. The fact that you posted this question to ask complete strangers if you're doing the right thing to me says you doubt yourself too much. Run with it dude, if it turns out not being a good idea you've just taken one more step towards being actually experienced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this question is too broad and likely would be re-closed as primarily opinion-based as Mike mentioned in the comments (I would agree with close votes of both types here). To me, it's too broad for a couple reasons:

- You are actually asking a series of questions rather than one question. Which one should an answerer address? All of them? One? A few? There's too much leeway here for someone to provide an answer to the question while potentially ignoring 90% of it.
- A good answer here would need to go into quite some depth, depending on how much of your question it responds to. Open-ended questions like "what do I do if X happens?" typically elicit a couple paragraphs in response. At that point, you're starting to approach a blog post. Now, I don't think it would be a problem if you had one specific scenario, perhaps with some existing code to frame the question around, that received a multi-paragraph answer. But since you have multiple questions, and more than one are rather open-ended, that means a good answer is just going to be too long.

Someone could come by and theoretically answer your question(s) with "yes, yes, no" or some such response, but that doesn't really do your question (or the site) justice.